Advanced Excel Formula, It's a Doozy
I have a major dilemma i am trying to get to work. Hopefully the hivemind can help me out!

In the example i have my reference key which is test 1 - 5 in columns I - K , in Column I i have a drop down menu for blank, Implement and disregard.
I want to make column C rows 3 -7 able to pull the data from column J but only if it shows "Implement" BUT i also want each row to pull the next available "Implement" so there is no spacing between them.
I originally used the "IF" formula to pull the data and used it to target each row in column I
=If(I3=$P$3,J3,IF(I4=$P$3,J4,If(I5=$P$3,J5 - Etc

for all of them. Which works for the first one, Row 3 of Column C. In rows 4-7 i just removed the top row of the key in the formula so it wont pull that one but used an "IF" to see if row 3 column C has "Test 1" in it to make sure then next available one is ready to be pulled.
=IF(C3=J3,IF(I5=$P$3,J5,If(I6=$P$3,J6,IF(I7=$P$3,J7,"")))IF(I7=$P$3,I7,"")

This works except at this point rows 4,5,&6 will all show "Test 4" because is the next one.
How do i make it so the formula in each row of column C can see if the previous one is used then move to the next Implement section which out any over lap?
I've tried a bunch of things and it ether breaks or doesn't pull the data at all and i'm just stuck!
Is this possible? Am i even making sense >_<

I suggest you update your example to show what you want as your expected outcome. Based on my understanding of what you wrote, use the FILTER() formula. If this is not available, then you need to retag to say what Excel version you are using.

We need clear, concise, examples of (input, output, and expected output) format this information to use a table within the body of the question. Screenshots of Excel are helpful for reference but are unhelpful to diagnose a solution.
